# Множественный LIKE

Tags: sql-server

В таблице с полем `txt nvarchar(100)` надо искать строки по нескольким шаблонам.
Сейчас выборка осуществляется следующим образом:

```
select * from tbl 
where txt like '%p1%' 
   or txt like '%p2%'
   or txt like '%p3%'
   or txt like '%p4%'
```

Хотелось бы сократить эту строку кода. Какие есть способы?
Примечание: полнотекстового поиска в базе данных нет и не будет.

Answer (score 4):

Не знаю на сколько это короче, но можно так:

```
select A.*
  from tbl A,
       ( values ('p1'),('p2'),('p3'),('p4') ) B(need)
 where A.txt like '%'+B.need+'%'
```

Answer (score 4):

Можно создать временную таблицу с шаблонами

```
create table #filter (pattern nvarchar(100))
insert #filter values ('a'), ('%b'), ('%c%')
```

Запрос для выборки строк, соответствующих шаблонам, может быть таким:

```
select t.* FROM tbl t 
  join #filter f ON t.txt like f.pattern
```